# Cython return tuple within cdef?

Tags: cython

Hi I am trying to convert a python code into cython in order to speed up its calculation. I am trying to return multiple arrays within the cython code from a `cdef` to `cpdef`. Based on classical C, I could either use a pointer or a tuple. I decide to use tuple because the size varies. I know the following code doesn't work, any help? Thank you!

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef tuple funA(double[:] X, double[:] Y): 
    cdef int nX, nY, i
    nX = len(X)
    nY = len(Y)

    for i in range(nX):
        X[i] = X[i]*X[i]

    for i in range(nY):
        Y[i] = Y[i]*Y[i]

    return X,Y

cpdef Run(double[:] X, double[:] Y)
    cdef Tuple1, Tuple2 = funA(X,Y)

    # Do some calculation with Tuple1 and Tuple2 
    # Example

    cdef int i, nTuple1, nTuple2

    nTuple1 = len(Tuple1)    
    for i in range(nTuple1):
        Tuple1[i] = Tuple1[i]**2

    nTuple2 = len(Tuple2)
    for i in range(nTuple2):
        Tuple2[i] = Tuple2[i]/2

    return Tuple1, Tuple2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a few indentation errors and missing colons. But your real issue is:

```
cdef Tuple1, Tuple2 = funA(X,Y)
```

Remove the `cdef` and it's fine. It doesn't look like `cdef` and tuple unpacking quite mix, and since you're treating them as Python objects it should be OK.

However, note that you don't really need to return anything from `funA` since you modify `X` and `Y` them in place there.

Comment: I remove the cdef as you suggested and I get a "Expected an identifier or literal".  Can you provide me with an example where in cpdef Run you call a function funA that returns 2 arrays? Thank you!

Comment: I think that's because you're missing a colon on the previous line.